# Slow serial communication between switch and python (pyserial)

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, pyserial, serial-communication

I am trying to make a program in python that changes the configuration of switchports on cisco/aruba switches.

Thus, I made an UI with pygame and used pyserial to take care of the serialcommands. To do this i understood that i had to thread the serialcommunication because it freezed up the UI.

I am very new to threading so I dont really know how it works, but now it seems like "everything" functions in my code as I want it to, aslong as you look past the serialcommunication being so slow. I have tried increasing the baudrate but that did not help.

```
import serial
import threading
ser = serial.Serial(
port = 'COM9', 
baudrate=9600, 
parity='N',    
stopbits=1,
bytesize=8,
timeout=8    
)

output = ""
command = ""
def run(run):

global output
global command


if (ser.isOpen() == False):
    ser.isOpen()
    print(ser.name)
command = '\r\n'
command = str.encode(command)
ser.write(command)
time.sleep(0.5)
ser.inWaiting()
input_data = ser.read(225) 
input_data = input_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
print(input_data)
command = (run)
command = str.encode(command + '\r\n')
ser.write(command) 
out = b''
time.sleep(.1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out = ser.readline(100)
    out = out.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    if out != '':
        print(out)
    output = out


check = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
def checkcommands():
global check

if "en" in output:
    check[0] = 1 
if "Admin" in output:
    check[1] = 1 
if "conf" in output:
    check[2] = 1 
if "int" in output:
    check[3] = 1 
if "mode acc" in output:
    check[4] = 1 
if "acc vlan" in output:
    check[5] = 1 
if "no shut" in output:
    check[6] = 1 
if "end" in output:
    check[7] = 1 
if "sh vlan" in output:
    check[8] = 1 
if "exit" in output:
    check[9] = 1 
    check[10] = 1

if check[0] != 1:
    run("en")
if check[1] != 1:
    run("Admin")
if check[2] != 1:
    run("conf t")
if check[3] != 1:
    run("int fa0/" + user_text) # port number (e.g. "1")
if check[4] != 1:
    run("switchport mode acc")
if check[5] != 1:
    run("switchport acc vlan " + user_text1) # vlan number (e.g. "1")
if check[6] != 1:
    run("no shut")
if check[7] != 1:
    run("end")
if check[8] != 1:
    run("sh vlan")
if check[9] != 1:
    run("exit")
if check[10] == 1:
    finished = True 




 program = threading.Thread(target=checkcommands)
 program.start()
```

I have played alot with this and my main problem has been that the commands have been entered too many times and/or too fast, but now that I used an array to check what commands are written, it is working prefect (besides being slow)

Do you guys see anything that makes this slow? it feels like it is written time.sleep(5) in the while loop.

Comment: last time I automated switches with python and telnet I used read_until function to respond as soon as I see the expected message in the stream

Comment: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until

Comment: Thanks, I will test :)